# Recreate BTRFS File System with DUP Profile

Tags: filesystems, btrfs

Is there a way to find out the exact parameters that were originally used when a BTRFS file system was created?  I'm working on a system with an older kernel version (4.4).  Because of the older kernel I believe I will be unable to convert an existing BTRFS file system to the DUP profile (for metadata and data) so my only recourse I think is to copy the data off the file system, recreate it with the DUP profile for both metadata and data, and copy the data back.  However since there are other parts and pieces involved I need to make 100% sure that the only thing that changes is the profile from single to DUP.  All other parameters need to stay the same.  How would I go about figuring out the various parameters that need to be specified for mkfs.btrfs?

Comment: `duplicity` is not a valid tag for this question as it relates to the backup software, not the btrfs dup profile.

Comment: @Ginnungagap You can just edit the post to remove the inappropriate tags. No need for a comment.

Answer (score 3):

[`btrfs filesystem df /path`](https://btrfs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/btrfs-filesystem.html) will show you the currently used profile for the given path.

You can convert an existing `single` profile to a `dup` profile using [`btrfs balance -mconvert=dup`](https://btrfs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/btrfs-balance.html) (to convert the metadata profile, read the manual for more).